# Avoiding Single Tap UIGestureRecognizer when Double Tap is Triggered when Using Storyboards

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, storyboard, uigesturerecognizer

I'm trying to add a double-tap UIGestureRecognizer to my Storyboard scene which already implements a single-tap UIGestureRecognizer.  Is there a Storyboard setting I can use which will prevent the single-tap gesture from firing when a single-tap gesture is triggered?  If not, how do I use requireGestureRecognizerToFail in conjunction with a Storyboard scene?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your code, you'll need to add this:

```
[self.singleRecognizer requireGestureRecognizerToFail:self.doubleTapRecognizer];
```